# Does the AWS Kinesis Firehose feature "Test with demo data" still exist?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-kinesis, amazon-kinesis-firehose

I have been working through AWS learning resources. In several sources, including the AWS doc https://docs.aws.amazon.com/firehose/latest/dev/test-drive-firehose.html, I have seen the "Test with demo data" feature of Kinesis Firehose used to generate test data when learning Kinesis. However, the feature does not appear on the page that the documentation claims. Videos in the Udemy AWS ML Course https://www.udemy.com/course/aws-machine-learning/ also use this "Test with demo data" feature; their UI does not match mine. My question was asked in the course forum as well and has no answer yet.

I have also contacted AWS support and will update when I hear back from them.

Comment: It seems this was a temporary bug of Kinesis console with a new GUI. Rollback and test with demo data confirmed.

Comment: Thank you, @shimo I tried again and can confirm that the "test with demo data" is still not available for me. So AWS did not Rollback for me. Are you suggesting that I can Rollback myself? If so, can you provide instructions or a link? Also, why did you Comment and not Answer? (sorry, I'm new here)

Comment: I checked Kinesis console just now and it was changed again, no test demo available. Weird but AWS changes GUI time to time and we cannot do ourselves. When I see test demo button, GUI was older version. So wait and see... / I use comments for relatively short answers, ideas and not-sure-things. Answers are for something long including doc quote, code. But this is just my own way.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The "Test with Demo" option has been removed from the Kinesis Firehouse page. However, AWS has introduced a new way to test your stream. Link below

[Link](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/big-data/test-your-streaming-data-solution-with-the-new-amazon-kinesis-data-generator/)

Comment: The "Test with demo data" feature is working for me as of 2023-09-20.